# How do you combinine a line graph and dot plot with ggplot2 using shiny?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to plot a line graph and a dot using ggplot2. The dot is created using the two inputs that the visitor types into ui.R. The ggplot equation works if I substitute numbers, e.g 18 and 24, for Zp and Kp. But I get an error, when I try to use the actual input values from the input fields "yrsales" and "yrinventory" into the ggplot expression. Please help. The code is shown below.

```
   Server.R
    library(shiny)
    library(datasets)
    library(ggplot2)

    sapparel <- read.csv("Apparel.csv")
    ssdrinks <- read.csv("Soft_drinks.csv")
    Zp = 0
    Kp = 0


    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset,
         "rock" = rock,
         "pressure" = pressure,
         "cars" = cars,
         "apparel" = sapparel,
         "soft drinks"= ssdrinks,
         )


    })  

    current <- reactive ({
      Zp <- input$yrsales

      Kp <- input$yrinventory  
    })


    output$newplot <- renderPlot ({

      # setting variables for default variable

        indInter <- 0.65
        indslope <- 0.87
        MinSale <- 13.37
        MaxSale <- 22.83  

        PredictInvtMin <- indInter+I(indslope*MinSale)
        PredictInvtMax <- indInter+I(indslope*MaxSale)

        Inventory <- c(PredictInvtMin, PredictInvtMax)
        Sales <- c(MinSale, MaxSale)    
        DatasetPredict.data <- data.frame(Sales, Inventory)


      ## plot a line graph for new input
      print(


       ((ggplot(data = DatasetPredict.data, aes(x = Sales, y = Inventory)) +         geom_line())+geom_point(aes(x= Zp, y = Kp, size=6))))
   })
          output$summary <- renderPrint({

      dataset <- datasetInput()
      summary(dataset)

    })
})
```

---

```
Ui.R


library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


#Application project title

  titlePanel("My reactivity project"),

  sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(
selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset to use:", choices = c("rock",     "pressure", "cars", "apparel", “drinks”)),

    helpText("If your sales was $ 30,450,000 million, enter 30.45 in the field"),
    numericInput("yrsales", "Enter your sales data:", value=20, step=.01),

    numericInput("yrinventory", "Enter your inventory data:", value=10, step=.01)

    ),

    mainPanel(

    verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
    plotOutput("newplot")
    )
    )
  ))
```

Comment: I think you may want to separate `current` into two calls -- then *I think* you should be able to do `x = currentZp()` and `y = currentKp()` - hard to say since this isn't fully reproducible.

Comment: Is there something about shiny that's making this complicated? Do you know how to combine plots using just ggplot in a standard R environment?